# I have tried this one and have given my approach below, but the answer is different. I would like someone to find out my mistake please.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $A,B,C$ be subsets of $X = \{1,2,3,\dots n\}$ such that: $A∩B∩C = \emptyset, A∩B ≠ \emptyset, B∩C ≠ \emptyset$. Find the number of such triplets $\{A,B,C\}$.

What I tried:

$3$ intersecting circles make $7$ regions, so triplets with numbers going to the $6$ regions (leaving $d$) $= 6^n$

Out of this we have to remove cases which do not have any numbers assigned to $b$ or $f$.

Therefore, required cases =
$6^n - 2\cdot5^n$. Refer this picture below.

[image: refer to this picture]

However, the answer given is $7^n - 2\cdot6^n + 5^n$. I would like someone to find out my mistake please.

Comment: You have the right idea, but there is also a region "outside all the circles", that is, there could be elements in none of $A,B,C$.  Give it another try.

Comment: Oh thanks, I always end up forgetting these small but important points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example: $A=\{1\}, B=\{1, 2\}, C=\{2\}$. This works, but you did not count it. This is because when calculating $6^n$, you assumed  that every number has to be in $a, b, c, e, f$ or $g$. Let's call the region outside the $3$ circles $h$. However, numbers can be in $h$. In my example, numbers $3, 4, \dots, n$ are in $h$.

Hence, for each number, there are $7$ options: $a, b, c, e, f, g$ or $h$, so we get a starting number of $7^n$. Try to figure out what you need to minus. I'm sure you can do it from here.